# Cannot change the mysql root user password

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried with the guide on mysql site, using mysqld --init-file=... command it run. but when i try to connect with the new password it says it is incorrect

Someone knows how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: It's highly unlikely https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html is incorrect; the much more probable scenario is you missed a step. Double check and try again.

Comment: If you've entered a SQL escaped password with `\`, then the actual password will be the unescaped version.